# nbconvert --to pdf works, but not from Jupyter Notebook menu (Python)

Tags: pdf, latex, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6, nbconvert

I upgraded recently every single Python lib on my computer, and I am not able to convert my Notebooks from the File Menu from Jupyter. I get the message:

```
500 : Internal Server Error
The error was:
nbconvert failed: '.\cumulative chart (for ANE17 poster).ipynb' exists but is not a directory
```

It is fine for me to convert through the command line, and actually this works:

```
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook .\cumulative chart (for ANE17 poster).ipynb to pdf
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in cumulative chart (for ANE17 poster)_files\
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\cumulative chart (for ANE17 poster)_files
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\cumulative chart (for ANE17 poster)_files
[NbConvertApp] Writing 26403 bytes to .\notebook.tex
[NbConvertApp] Building PDF
[NbConvertApp] Running xelatex 3 times: ['xelatex', '.\\notebook.tex']
[NbConvertApp] Running bibtex 1 time: ['bibtex', '.\\notebook']
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | b had problems, most likely because there were no citations
[NbConvertApp] PDF successfully created
[NbConvertApp] Writing 43091 bytes to .\cumulative chart (for ANE17 poster).pdf
```

But still, what happened to Jupyter, and/or nbconvert, and/or the Pandoc/MiKTex lib? Thank you for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I had the same problem after Jupyter re-installation. According to [this page](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2987), it's a bug in recent versions of `notebook` package starting from 5.2, which should be fixed in later versions. Currently, the solution would be just to downgrade the `notebook` package, like:

```
pip install -U "notebook<5.2"
```

At least it worked for me.